# How to ensure that the certificate that I receive from the server is the correct certificate?

Tags: c#

I have gRPC application and I would like to validate in the client that the certificate that it receives from the server is the correct certificate.

For that, I distribute the public certificate of the server with the client. SO I can validate the certificate, but which is the best way to validate?

I can use the method GetPublicKey(), that it returns the public key, that if I am not wrong, it is then thumbprint.

But I can use GetCertHash(), that returns the hash of the certificate. I guess it could be more secure, becuase it is the hash of the whole certificate, not only the thumbprint, that perhaps it could be duplicate easier.

But it is a self signed certificate, so it was create from a self signed CA, so I would like to know if it would be some way to check if the certificate was created from this CA. For that, I could distribute the CA with the client application.

So in sumary, I would like to know which is the best way to validate the server certificate, and I would like to validate its value and check if it was created by the CA that the clients has.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your question C# specific?

Comment: Yes, it is an C# especfic question in this case, but It is using a X509 certificate, I guess that it could be the same for another languages. But in my case, yes, it is a C# .NET 7 question.

Comment: You can add the CA as a trusted CA, then call the [`Verfiy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?view=net-8.0) method on the `X509Certificate2` object.